# Is there a way to retrieve all contents from a versioned Amazon S3 bucket as of a particular datetime

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is it possible via the AWS CLI or via some third-party tool to easily download all contents of a versioned bucket as it was on a particular datetime?

I.E. I would like to retrieve the version of each object in the bucket which would have been regarded as the 'latest' version on the given date.

Comment: I would still like an answer to this, if anyone can help!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/808374/157994

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore a versioned S3 bucket to a particular point in time](https://serverfault.com/questions/589713/restore-a-versioned-s3-bucket-to-a-particular-point-in-time)

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the [aws cli](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cli/), I only see the versioning functionality exposed in the [s3api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/index.html) section, not in the [s3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html) section.

From what I've understood it's only possible to fetch previous versions of objects based on their version id.

> By default, the GET operation returns the current version of an
>   object. To return a different version, use the versionId subresource.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html for examples and additional details

To solve what you're asking for my understanding is that, unless you have been tracking the version ids yourself, you will need to fetch a list of the versions first to determine which ones to get.

> You can use the versions subresource to list metadata about all of the versions of objects in a bucket. You can also use request parameters as selection criteria to return metadata about a subset of all the object versions.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETVersion.html for details.

That response would have data like the following for each version that matches your query:

```
    <Version>
        <Key>my-image.jpg</Key>
        <VersionId>3/L4kqtJl40Nr8X8gdRQBpUMLUo</VersionId>
        <IsLatest>true</IsLatest>
         <LastModified>2009-10-12T17:50:30.000Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>&quot;fba9dede5f27731c9771645a39863328&quot;</ETag>
        <Size>434234</Size>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
        <Owner>
            <ID>75aa57f09aa0c8caeab4f8c24e99d10f8e7faeebf76c078efc7c6caea54ba06a</ID>
            <DisplayName>mtd@amazon.com</DisplayName>
        </Owner>
    </Version>
```

In terms of the aws cli this would be [`aws s3api get-object --version-id ...`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html) and [`aws s3api list-object-versions ...`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-object-versions.html) respectively for the API calls mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you, while not an quick easy solution, this will help me write a script to perform the task I need to complete.  Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: hard to believe Amazon haven't allowed for this

Answer (score 3):

Using [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) you can do a restore from a point in time by including the parameter `--time`. You can refer to [this link](http://frontmag.no/artikler/utvikling/amazon-s3-backup-solution2) for some examples of use with Amazon S3 service.

```
duplicity --time 2012-10-01T01:00:00 s3+http://backup_bucket_url /local_restore_path
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Though I'd prefer to not have to use Duplicity, given that I will need to deal with the hassle of having a huge set of Duplicity files (my data set is about 900gb).